# mysql indexing date vs datetime on large audit table

Tags: mysql, sql, percona

I have an audit table that is currently running at around 25M rows on innodb and growing about 1M rows a month.
I currently have an index on the datetime column.
For performance reasons, if a user searches it limits to the current day.
Would index performance be better if I split the datetime into two separate fields and had an index just on the date field.
I suspect this would also create a smaller index as you are not indexing each and every separate second of the datetime field.
I may also benefit from partition this table.

Ps. Currently running percona 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the query is phrased.  If the query is phrased as:

```
where date(datetimecol) = curdate()
```

Then the index isn't going to be used.  Adding a date column with an index would improve performance, if the query were phrased as:

```
where datecol = curdate()
```

If the query is phrased as:

```
where datetimecol >= curdate () and
      datetimecol < date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day)
```

then the index will (probably) be used.

Comment: I do not use function as you have shown on the first example.

I was more thinking about the performance doing a WHERE over say a 6 month time frame on a DATE field vs DATETIME field.

It may be that B-Tree indexes are already optimized for this situation so there would be no real difference in speed.

Comment: @tsmgeek . . . I'm not sure what your concern is.  If you are retrieving data from a 6-month timeframe, then the time to fetch the rows might dominate the query.

Comment: We also run a limit so a user never pulls back more than 500 audits on a single page, but the initial search time can take a while on a large data set.
This is more about index optimisation, the index may be overly large on a DATETIME column where nearly every row would be unique but if I was to use DATE then it would have a better cardinality.

Comment: @tsmgeek . . . You should ask another question and show the entire query.  For instance, if you have an `order by`, then that is probably responsible for the poor performance.